# Using bash for iterating in dictionary like formats

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a python like dictionary in an input file:

```
$ cat test.txt
db={1:['a','b','c','d'], 2:['aa','bb','cc','dd']}
```

Each list in dictionary only has 4 indexes not less or more.
I need a result like:

```
one1="a"
two1="b"
three1="c"
four1="d"

one2="aa"
two2="bb"
three2="cc"
four2="dd"
```

I know this is simple if we use python here, but I should do the job in bash script.
Is it possible? How can I do the job using bash script?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `I have` - is `db={1:['a','b','c','d'], 2:['aa','bb','cc','dd']}` a line in a file, is it a variable you're trying to populate in a shell script, is it a variable being populated in a python script or something else? Please [edit] your question to clarify what your input is, get rid of all the `...`s that are cluttering up your sample input and expected output and making it untestable, and show what you've tried yourself so far to solve the problem.

Comment: @Ed Morton, thank you, in my bash script I have to get some variables from a file so thought the file format would be good in dictionary format. so I have a test.txt that contains this dictionary format.

Comment: Don't add information in comments, [edit] your question to provide all information.

Comment: @Morteza.J : Why did you use an _awk_ tag, if you are interested in a bash solution? If you are willing to go for a different programming language such as _awk_, you can as well use _python_ or _Perl_ or whatever else for it, since they all can be invoked from bash.

Comment: @user1934428 the big difference between awk and python or perl is that awk is a standard UNIX tool available on all UNIX boxes while the other too aren't. If someone asks for a "bash script" they very, **VERY**, rarely mean a script using all shell builtings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to strip off all the unnecessary characters and loop through them to get your result

```
#!/bin/bash
db="{1:['a','b','c','d'], 2:['aa','bb','cc','dd']}"
count=1
for items in `echo $db|sed 's/{//;s/}//'`
do
        echo one${count} = `echo $items|sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//'|cut -d ',' -f1`
        echo two${count} = `echo $items|sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//'|cut -d ',' -f2`
        echo three${count} = `echo $items|sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//'|cut -d ',' -f3`
        echo four${count} = `echo $items|sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//'|cut -d ',' -f4`
        echo ''
        count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

Output

```
one1 = 'a'
two1 = 'b'
three1 = 'c'
four1 = 'd'

one2 = 'aa'
two2 = 'bb'
three2 = 'cc'
four2 = 'dd'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great. how can I add output to array. for example: echo one${count} = `echo $items|sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//'|cut -d ',' -f1` add this results to an array

Comment: In addition to simply being the wrong approach (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)), that script literally contains more bugs than lines of code. Copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about **some** (but probably not all) of the issues.

Comment: @Ed Morton, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a single `sed` command (Tested in GNU sed 4.8. Assumes the whole expression is in a single line and there is no embedded single quote between a pair of matching single quotes):

```
echo "db={1:['a','b','c','d'], 2:['aa','bb','cc','dd']}" |
sed -E "s/^[^{]*\{//; s/\}[^}]*$//; s/([^:]+):\['([^']*)','([^']*)','([^']*)','([^']*)'\](, *)?/one\1='\2'\ntwo\1='\3'\nthree\1='\4'\nfour\1='\5'\n\n/g"
```

outputs

```
one1='a'
two1='b'
three1='c'
four1='d'

one2='aa'
two2='bb'
three2='cc'
four2='dd'
```

**Explanation:**

```
-E
```

Use extended regular expression so that we don't quote `(`, `)`, `+` characters.

```
s/^[^{]*\{//;
```

Deletes characters at the beginning of the line until and including the `{` character

```
s/\}[^}]*$//;
```

Deletes the `}` character and trailing characters (if any) at the end of line

```
s/([^:]+):\['([^']*)','([^']*)','([^']*)','([^']*)'\](, *)?/one\1='\2'\ntwo\1='\3'\nthree\1='\4'\nfour\1='\5'\n\n/g
  -------    -------   -------   -------   -------   -----  -----------------------------------------------------
     1          2         3         4         5        6                      R
```

1: Captures the text until `:`
2: Captures the text between the first pair of single quotes
3: Captures the text between the second pair of single quotes
4: Captures the text between the third pair of single quotes
5: Captures the text between the fourth pair of single quotes
6: Captures the `,` and any number of trailing space characters. This subexpression is not used in the replacement text. `?` means this is optional.
R: Replacement text. `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, `\4`, and `\5` are replaced with the corresponding captured text.
The `g` flag at the end of the `s` command ensures that the replacement is applied to *all* matches.

Comment: Nice Explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will work robustly using any awk in any shell on all UNIX boxes and is trivial to enhance if you need to use it for more than 4 items per list just by adding more names for numbers to the string in the BEGIN section:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { split("one two three four",names) }
{
    while ( match($0,/[0-9]+:\[('[^']*',?)+/) ) {
        idx = list = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)

        sub(/:.*/,"",idx)
        sub(/[^[]+\[/,"",list)

        split(list,items,/'/)
        for (i=2; i in items; i+=2) {
            printf "%s%d=\"%s\"\n", names[i/2], idx, items[i]
        }
        print ""

        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
one1="a"
two1="b"
three1="c"
four1="d"

one2="aa"
two2="bb"
three2="cc"
four2="dd"
```